# how to apply MCI to capture microphone input and process in C

Tags: c, windows, audio, microphone

I wanted to capture and process audio input through microphone in C. I couldn't find specific functions to handle input devices. So I moved to use MCI of windows to not use other open source tools/software.
While trying to apply the functions specific to MCI to record, process and save as `.WAV` file, am facing a lot of errors which refer to other built in libraries. For instance, here is one sample code I fetched over the net:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <mmsystem.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
 {
  HWAVEOUT hWaveOut;
  WAVEFORMATEX wfx; 
  MMRESULT result;

    wfx.nSamplesPerSec = 44100; 
    wfx.wBitsPerSample = 16; 
    wfx.nChannels = 2;
    wfx.cbSize = 0; 
    wfx.wFormatTag = WAVE_FORMAT_PCM;
    wfx.nBlockAlign = (wfx.wBitsPerSample >> 3) * wfx.nChannels;
    wfx.nAvgBytesPerSec = wfx.nBlockAlign * wfx.nSamplesPerSec;

    if(waveOutOpen(&hWaveOut,        WAVE_MAPPER,&wfx,0,0,CALLBACK_NULL)     !=  MMSYSERR_NOERROR)
    {
     fprintf(stderr, "unable to open WAVE_MAPPER device\n");
      ExitProcess(1);
    }
    printf("The Wave Mapper device was opened successfully!\n");
    waveOutClose(hWaveOut);
    return 0;
   }
```

Comment: And the errors are....?

Comment: Do you have an actual question?

Comment: Well, yeah.. I see question marks in comments only..

Comment: The errors are multiple and repetetive. for instance 263 C:\Dev-     Cpp\include\windef.h syntax error at '##' token

Comment: If you want to get any help, you should include all of the relevant information in the question.

Comment: it happens in thousands . i didnt even know  where to access windef.h except as itopens in new tap. it happens not only to windef.h but also winbase.h, and winuser.h. i must have made terrible silly mistake or didnt know what to include . can someone out there please help me how to fix this? I would appreciate if i can see one simple working code that uses the functions used above

Comment: This compiles except for linker errors. Did you look at [waveOutOpen function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd743866%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)? You need to link with `Winmm.lib` but you do not need to explicitly `#include <mmsystem.h>` because you have `#include <windows.h>`

Comment: @WeatherVane Looks like the OP has problem compiling. I would say he screwed up one of the headers. Or the compiler settings are wrong.

Comment: so how do i link the Winnmm.lib ? do i just include it? when i include this , it says no such file or directory

Comment: @WeatherVane am new to this . can help me understand what u mean?

Comment: I do not use an IDE, I make executables from a console command line. My current (project) folder contains a file called `MAKEFILE` which instructs the compiler tool chain what to do. One of its lines instructs what library modules to link to the executable. Since this test project is for simple C testing, its makefile does not mention any windows libraries to link, which is why I got the error I mentioned above, and, presumably, relates also to you own situation, as you refer to "lots of errors from built-in libraries".

Comment: @WeatherVane,Eugene Sh thank you